# python checking if two variables are in a list

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and in the process of rewriting an old Python script, I came across these lines:

```
value1 = 'some val 1'
value2 = 'some val 2'
some_list = #list of values

if (value1, value2) in some_list:
```

Does this check if `value1` and `value2` are in the list?

I googled how to do that and the answers show different approaches, and I didn't see any suggesting using the above code.

Is this doing something else? Should I keep it or change it?

Comment: No, this checks to see whether the tuple `(value1, value2)` is present in the list. Not the individual values themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(value1, value2)` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).  Your check is seeing if that tuple is in the list.  For example:

```
mylist = [4, 5, (4, 5), 6]
(4, 5) in mylist
>True #because the tuple (4, 5) is in the list
(5, 6)
>False #because although 5 and 6 are both in the list, the tuple is not.
```

If you want to see if every item in the tuple is in the list, use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) as mentioned by @apero:

```
mylist = [4, 5, 6, 7]
all(x in mylist for x in (4, 5, 6))
>True
all(x in mylist for x in (4, 5, 8))
>False
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `all`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> values = (1, 3)
>>> all(value in lst for value in values)
True
>>> values1 = (1, 6)
>>> all(value in lst for value in values1)
False
```

`all` evaluates to `True` **only when all the values match the condition**, in this case "being in the list". This is a really useful [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) method because it will stop evaluating as soon as 1 of the values does not match the condition. This technique is called **[short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**.

It behaves like `if <test> and <test1> and <test2> .... :` which evaluates each test one by one, from left to right and returns False as soon as one of the test doesn't pass.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, using sets:

```
>>> to_find = {4, 5, 6}
>>> mylist = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> to_find.intersection(mylist) == to_find
True
>>> mylist = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> to_find.intersection(mylist) == to_find
False
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if any of the values are in the list:

```
>>> all(x in some_list for x in [value1, value2])
```

what you are doing now is checking if the tuple is in the list